# IOS create textsize with CGSize depreciated method

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgsize

Hi i am reacreating the textsize with these code

```
CGSize textSize = [self.text sizeWithFont:self.font
                        constrainedToSize:self.frame.size
                            lineBreakMode:self.lineBreakMode];
```

the above is depreciate. how can we change it inorder to keep the purpose?

Any help is much appreciate. Thanks!

My whole function purpose is to align the UIlable top (vertical)

```
- (void)alignTop
{
    CGSize textSize = [self.text sizeWithFont:self.font
                            constrainedToSize:self.frame.size
                                lineBreakMode:self.lineBreakMode];

    CGRect textRect = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x,
                                 self.frame.origin.y,
                                 self.frame.size.width,
                                 textSize.height);
    [self setFrame:textRect];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Comment: "deprecated"?  That would depend on what version of iOS you were targetting and you don't tell us, so who knows?

Comment: Sorry, the code is from old project ios 6. now need to update for 7+!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
 - (CGRect)boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize)size options:(NSStringDrawingOptions)options attributes:(nullable NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)attributes context:(nullable NSStringDrawingContext *)context
```

OR use this

```
 - (CGSize)sizeWithAttributes:(nullable NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)attrs
```

this is an example

```
+ (CGSize)neededSizeForText:(NSString*)text withFont:(UIFont*)font andMaxWidth:(float)maxWidth
{
    NSStringDrawingOptions options = (NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading|NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin);

    NSMutableParagraphStyle * style =  [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
    [style setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    [style setAlignment:NSTextAlignmentRight];

    NSDictionary *textAttibutes = @{NSFontAttributeName : font,
                                    NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : style};

    CGSize neededTextSize = [text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(maxWidth, 500) options:options attributes:textAttibutes context:nil].size;

    return neededTextSize;
}
```

I hope this helps

Comment: thanks, I just edit the question. The purpose is to align UIlable (vertical) top. Is the maxWidth is frame.size.width?

Comment: maxWidth is by example the width of your view container for your label - your margins, in your case is your frame.size.width